# UrlFetchApp.fetch will abort the script?

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I create a spreadsheet with 3 sheets, "Links", "Valid Links" and "Invalid links", then use the following code to check each row in the "Links" sheet, as below:

```
function myFunction() {
  var rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Links").getDataRange().getValues();
  
  rows.forEach(function(row, index) 
  {
    if (index !== 0) 
    { 
      var url = row[1];
      var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
      var number = page.match("sample.com");
      
      if (!number)
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Valid Links").appendRow(url);
      else
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Invalid Links").appendRow(url);
    }
  });
}
```

However, when I debug to UrlFetchApp.fetch(url), the script suddenly aborts. No error or exception are shown. Why?

I have asked this question on Google Script Community, but no one answers. So I have to ask it here. I don't know how to get the specific URL for my question on Google Script Community, so I have to copy & paste the question. Sorry about that.

**Update**

With the help of Tanaike, I fix my bug:

1. I think row[1] refers to column A, but it actually to column B, which is an undefined value, so cause the bug.
2. !number should be changed to number, as if (number) means a match so the result is valid link.

Comment: View >executions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put the value to `Valid Links` and `Invalid Links` sheets by checking the URL using `UrlFetchApp.fetch`.
- The URLs for checking are put in the column "B" in `Links` sheet.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, how about using `muteHttpExceptions` as the option of `UrlFetchApp.fetch`? By this, the response value can be retrieved even when the request is failed.

  - The default value of `muteHttpExceptions` is `false`. In this case, when the request occurs error, the script is stopped. It seems that this is the current specification. But when `muteHttpExceptions` is `true`, the script is not stopped even when the request occurs error.
- In your script, `appendRow(url)` is used and `var url = row[1];` is the value from the column "B". In this case, `url` is required to be `[url]`.
- In the case of `var number = page.match("sample.com");`, when `sample.com` is included in `page`, `url` is put in `Invalid Links` sheet. When `sample.com` is NOT included in `page`, `url` is put in `Valid Links` sheet. I'm not sure whether this might be the result you expect. But please be careful this.
- I think that when `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` is used, the process cost will be able to be reduced a little.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  // Added
  var rows = ss.getSheetByName("Links").getDataRange().getValues();  // Added
  rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
    if (index !== 0) {
      var url = row[1];
      var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true}).getContentText();  // Modified
      var number = page.match("sample.com");
      if (!number) {
        ss.getSheetByName("Valid Links").appendRow([url]);  // Added
      } else {
        ss.getSheetByName("Invalid Links").appendRow([url]);  // Added
      }
    }
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- When `fetchAll` is used, the process cost might be able to be reduced more. But I'm not sure about the number of URLs. So I modified your script like above without using `fetchAll` method.

#### References:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))
- [appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)

### Added:

About [the following new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64194308/urlfetchapp-fetch-will-abort-the-script/64194545?noredirect=1#comment113526921_64194545),

> One more question, when url is wisesoft.co.uk, I get error SSL Error wisesoft.co.uk (line 10, file "Code") and the script also abort. I use Chrome and find https has error but the site can be visited via http version, how to ignore such an error and continue fetch the contents?

in this case, how about using `try...catch` as follows?

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rows = ss.getSheetByName("Links").getDataRange().getValues();
  rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
    if (index !== 0) {
      var url = row[1];
      try {
        var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true}).getContentText();
        var number = page.match("sample.com");
        if (!number) {
          ss.getSheetByName("Valid Links").appendRow([url]);
        } else {
          ss.getSheetByName("Invalid Links").appendRow([url]);
        }
      } catch(e) {
        ss.getSheetByName("Invalid Links").appendRow([url]);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

- [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: I know the bug of my code, I think row[1] is referring to column A, but it referring to column B, which is an undefined value.

Comment: One more question, when url is https://www.wisesoft.co.uk, I get error SSL Error https://www.wisesoft.co.uk/ (line 10, file "Code") and the script also abort. I use Chrome and find https has error but the site can be visited via http version, how to ignore such an error and continue fetch the contents?

Comment: @alancc Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, in that case, how about using `try...catch`? [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: What I can do after the exception raised, re-fetch with the non-http version?

Comment: @alancc Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about `What I can do after the exception raised, re-fetch with the non-http version?`, for your new question, I added one more sample script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I have fixed my issue again. Anyway, is there a way to full compile the script before running it. I find a lot of bugs are raised due to my typos.

Comment: @alancc Thank you for replying. I'm glad your 2nd question was resolved. About your 3rd question of `Anyway, is there a way to full compile the script before running it.`, unfortunately, I cannot answer for this. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize that I cannot answer for your all questions. I think that I have to study more.

Comment: No problem. You have helped me a lot. Thank you very much. Have a nice day!

Comment: And god bless Trump.